# SpringFox Swagger not working as expected on IBM Liberty 19.0.0.1

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, websphere-liberty, springfox

Attached below (Swagger on Tomcat) (click to zoom-in) - My application's Swagger UI on Tomcat 9
[image]

Attached (Swagger on Liberty) (click to zoom-in) - My application's Swagger UI on Liberty 19.0.0.1
[image]

In Tomcat, as can be seen, the 200 response body is clearly shown and the "Try it out" option's execution is flawless.

However, in Liberty, the 200 response body is not shown and "Try it out" execution results in a Response Body filled with errors as follows (truncated):

```
<H1>Error Page Exception</H1>
<H4>SRVE0260E: The server cannot use the error page specified for your application to handle the Original Exception printed below.</H4>
<BR><H3>Original Exception: </H3>
<B>Error Message: </B>Unauthorized<BR>
<B>Error Code: </B>401<BR>
<B>Target Servlet: </B>dispatcherServlet<BR>
<B>Error Stack: </B><BR>
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: Unauthorized

<BR>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppDispatcherContext.sendError(WebAppDispatcherContext.java:630)

<BR>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppDispatcherContext.sendError(WebAppDispatcherContext.java:648)

<BR>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse.sendError(SRTServletResponse.java:1328)

<BR>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendError(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:164)

<BR>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendError(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:164)

<BR>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.sendError(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:119)

<BR>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint.commence(BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint.java:61)

<BR>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint.commence(DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint.java:95)

<BR>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.sendStartAuthentication(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:213)

<BR>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.handleSpringSecurityException(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:185)

<BR>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:141)

<BR>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
...
...
more
```

At the same time, the Liberty console has the following error (scroll to the rigt for more):

```
Error reported: 406

[ERROR   ] Error Page Exception:
                                                                                                               0-0

                                                                                                               Error Page Exception
                                                                                                               com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: SRVE0295E
```

My Liberty's server.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server description="new server">

    <!-- Enable features -->
    <featureManager>
        <feature>webProfile-8.0</feature>
        <feature>springBoot-2.0</feature>
        <feature>servlet-4.0</feature>
    </featureManager>

    <basicRegistry/>

    <!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
    <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
                  httpPort="9090"
                  httpsPort="9443" />

    <!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
    <applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>

</server>
```

My application uses Java 8, Spring Boot (2.1.3) with Spring Integration, Spring Security, Spring REST Docs, Springfox 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT and Log4j 2.

Can someone please help point to the underlying reason behind Liberty not being able to display the Swagger response or provision the "Try it out" feature? Like I said, the same is working smoothly on Tomcat 9.

Sincerely,
Bharath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem may be due to deploying a SpringBoot 2.1.3 application on Liberty 19.0.0.1, which supports SpringBoot 1.5 and 2.0 applications, but lacks the capability to [thin embedded server dependencies from Spring Boot 2.1](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues/6360) applications.  This capability has since been added to [Liberty 19.0.0.2](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/releases).  Please update to Liberty 19.0.0.2 and retry your scenario. And if the update does not resolve the problem, I've opened [open-liberty  issue 6870](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues/6870) for further discussion and discovery.

Comment: My company didn't allow for an upgrade to Liberty 19.0.0.2.
So I downgraded to Spring Boot 2.0 (which is good for my project) on Liberty 19.0.0.1 worked for me!